# How much dangerous rm -rf is?

Tags: security, mount, rm

Does `rm -rf dir/` erase filesystems mounted below `dir/` (say in `dir/a`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, rm will not erase filesystems. However it will delete the files on them.

Note that the `-r` means recursive so it would delete:

- All files in `dir/`
- all directories in `dir/`
- and do the same for all subdirectories (including /dir/a, or if it exists /dir/a/b/ ... )